# VS2015: LNK2019 error when linking with Muiload.lib

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2015

I'm experimenting the next error when including `muiload.h` and linking with `muiload.lib` and calling `LoadMUILibrary` in *Visual Studio 2015*:

> Muiload.lib(muiload.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __vsnwprintf referenced in function "long __stdcall StringVPrintfWorkerW(unsigned short *,unsigned int,unsigned int
>   *,unsigned short const *,char *)" (?StringVPrintfWorkerW@@YGJPAGIPAIPBGPAD@Z)

Maybe something wrong in `muiload.lib`?

Comment: I had the same problem with an old DirectX SDK sample. Your solution worked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solved adding the additional library **legacy_stdio_definitions.lib** to the linker input as explained in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5150eeec-4427-440f-ab19-aecb26113d31/updated-to-vs-2015-and-now-get-unresolved-external-errors?forum=vcgeneral

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to linking against `legacy_stdio_definitions.lib` is to redefine these function signatures to match their deprecated style:

```
int (WINAPIV * __vsnprintf)(char *, size_t, const char*, va_list) = _vsnprintf;
int (WINAPIV * __vsnwprintf)(wchar_t *, size_t, const wchar_t*, va_list) = _vsnwprintf;
```

One benefit of this is that it avoids other possible linker definition issues caused by including the legacy library.

Note that this should be defined in a compiler unit (.cpp) rather than in a header file.